SPA express routing but allowing NPM Package imports
I tried to create a single page application which serves index.html from an express router. My express router looks like this:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs")

const app = express();

const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const urlPath = path.join(__dirname, req.path)
  if(req.path === "/"){
    res.sendFile(indexPath)
  } else{
    fs.access(urlPath, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
      if(err){
        res.sendFile(indexPath)
      } else{
        res.sendFile(urlPath);
      }
    })
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}`);
});


I tried to prevent using a static folder, but also tried it with one and still have the same problem.
My problem is the following: This express router serves the html file on every route, except when a file is requested, for example in a import like import { func } from "file.js". The problem is that I know can't import npm packages, because it'll try to affiliate them with files. import { v4 } from "uuid" gives the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "uuid". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I tried different methods for routing and modifying the server file but I didn't get anywhere, that's why I'm asking here. The goal is to have a server that serves index.html for every route and handling the routing in the client. I also need to be able to import and export files inside the module in my client and additionally to files I want to be able to use npm packages.
I'd be really glad if someone could help. Thank you.

You can either bundle the frontend app or use an import map.
